# Import Folder as Layers (for sub-folders individually)

Tags: javascript, photoshop, subdirectory

I would like some additions to [this free script](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/downloads/Import%20Folder%20as%20Layers%202-0-0.jsx) (thanks to trevor morris)

I just want this script to do sub-folders. How do I go with it?

I can get subfolders with a code I found at [Adobe's site](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1246514):

```
function scanSubFolders(tFolder, mask) { // folder object, RegExp or string
var sFolders = new Array(); 
var allFiles = new Array(); 
sFolders[0] = tFolder; 
for (var j = 0; j < sFolders.length; j++)
```

I'm trying to smush them together. I mailed the free scripts owner for a free estimate, He has not responded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method 'getFiles' on a folder to get files or subfolders.  For more info check out the 'File System Access' section of the JavaScript Tools Guide that came with your photoshop installation.